# Django Determine if Min is unique

Tags: python, django

```
class Score(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Player", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    strokes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm having trouble using aggregation and annotation to accomplish the following with a set of Scores. Should I be using a different approach?

For a set of Scores, find the minimum number of strokes, then determine if it is unique. For example, if I had a set of scores with the following stroke values:

`[4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]` The minimum amount of strokes is 4, and 4 is NOT unique.

`[3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]` The minimum amount of strokes is 3, and 3 is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain that in two queries:

1. first we retrieve the minimum value; and
2. then we count the number of times that value occurs.

So we can query with:

```
from django.db.models import Min

min_score = Score.objects.aggregate(min_score=Min('score'))['score']
num_min_score = Score.objects.filter(score=min_score).count()
```

Comment: I was able to use this information to solve the problem, thank you. In ```Score.objects.aggregate(min_score=Min('score'))['score']``` , What is ['score'] for on the end? I wasn't able to get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

What about counting the occurrences of the lowest value?

```
vals = [4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
vals.count(min(vals))

vals2 = [3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]
vals2.count(min(vals2))
```